# set drawer menu icons dynamically

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Question :- I want to set different menu icons for different items in the navigation drawer. I Know how to set the icon for the items, but I could set only one icon for every item in the list.I want to set different icons dynamically.

My code is :

```
@Override
public View getView(NLevelItem item) 
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category);
    TextView plusIcon = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_plus);
    CategoryBean categoryBean = (CategoryBean) item.getWrappedObject();
    tv.setText(" "+categoryBean.getName());

    //here is where I set the Icon
    tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.rsz_ic_home, 0,0, 0);
    return view;
}
```

Note :- I am using nlevel menu so I dont want icon for every item. I want icon for only parent item, hence I am not using imageview in my layout. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy.

You must work with a string-array for the item's name, and with a array to the item's icon. And obviously, you must create a constructor-class to create each item of the drawer.

I think this tutorial will help you a lot.

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: @Marconi Vignoli What should I do to dynamically get those icons from server? How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Store the id of the drawable in your item and get its value in your getView method:

```
@Override
public View getView(NLevelItem item) 
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category);
    TextView plusIcon = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_plus);
    CategoryBean categoryBean = (CategoryBean) item.getWrappedObject();
    tv.setText(" "+categoryBean.getName());

    //here is where I set the Icon
    tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(item.getDrawableId(), 0,0, 0);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: for getting the drawable id I need to set it first. How would I set it? I am setting the values of menu in a categorybean,how can I pass different values of icon in the categorybean? do I need to store the icon id somewhere in a collection or something else?

Comment: What should I do to dynamically get those icons from server? How could I do that?